# Does Application instance exist after starting any component?

Tags: singleton, android

Should I be sure that if any of my application component is started (onCreate for Activity/Service, onReceived for BroadcastReceiver, etc) then my application instance of Application class already exists?

I have static field "instance" in my Application class

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static MyApplication instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    instance = this;
    super.onCreate();
}

    public MyApplication getInstance(){
         return instance;
    }
```

Of course this class is registered in manifest. I wonder if usage of static instance field is safe and will always return me proper value.
I didn't use content providers before, but will it work for content providers too?

Answer (score -3):

If onCreate can only be accessed from a single thread, and is only created once, you should be fine. See this post for an example of how to implement the Singleton in a thread-safe way (albeit in C#). The static reference is indeed thread-safe providing you also have a static initializer.

http://www.codeinthemorning.com/design-patterns/singleton-pattern/

Comment: Delete this - it's not what he's asking